# Triggering click event crashes the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check this link:
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ev3FR/1/)

When a div is clicked I want the link inside to trigger a click event.
but the console shows that the click event keeps triggering until the browser crashes. Why is this happening? And whats the solution?

The real div's has alot of content inside of it so I don't want the `<a>` tag to cover the whole div or wrap the div inside a `<a>` tag. This function is intended to work on mobile devices.

Comment: What is the goal of triggering the click event of `<a>` element?

Comment: Timestamp: 27/03/2013 19:34:06
Error: too much recursion
Source File: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js
Line: 2749

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in every `click` event, you call `click` again, resulting in never ending recursion.

Since your click handler is on `div`s with the `box` class, clicking on anything inside of those `div`s will cause the `click` event on the `div`.

It seems like you're wanting a click on the `div` to follow the link? Instead of triggeing a `click` on the link, you could do this:

```
window.location = $(this).find(".link").attr("href");
```

Comment: @VisioN I think recursion would be when you want the loop to happen. Plus, there's no base case.

Comment: @G_M It's not a loop; the function essentially calls itself, so that's recursion. The lack of a base case is what's causing the problem: it recurses infinitely.

Comment: Yeah, and it is also worth to extend the answer with *why* the recursion happens.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  It stops the infinite loop.  But a better question is why do this?

```
$(".box").click(function(e){
    console.log("clicked");
    $(this).find(".link").trigger("click");
});

$(".link").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Or, you know, just don't call the `$(this).find(".link").trigger("click");` line because it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Lol, true.  But ain't no body got time for that logic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger a click on ".link", that event bubbles up to its parent and eventually reaches ".box" again. Hence going into recursion.
To prevent this, You could do something like

```
$(".box").click(function(e){
    if(e.currentTarget == e.target)
    {    
        console.log("clicked");
        $(this).find(".link").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

The e.target is the element where the event occured and the e.currentTarget is the element on which the event was bound.

One more alternate solution would be (recommended),

```
$(".box").click(function(e){
    console.log("clicked");
    $(this).find(".link").trigger("click");       
});
$(".link").click(function (e)
{
    /*This would prevent a click triggered on ".link" to propagate upto its parent i.e ".box" */
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```